# GWT SSL connection

Tags: gwt, ssl

On GWT (Jetty development mode) server side I am trying to connect with 
`final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);`
I connect to the server without errors but when I am trying to get information from the service I get the following error.
`PIDjavax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty`

This snipset of code is working as expected when not running under GWT but as a pure jsp project calling the servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a pure Java problem and not associated with GWT.
I was loading all security parameters with bean, and truststore parameters for a reason could not be found, so got the exception.
I loaded manually the truststore and problem solved.